# Need help working out why my simple app crashes

Tags: android

I've just got into trying to learn Java over the past few days. I've been jumping between tutorials, etc to try and pick up some of the basics.

Currently it starts on a splash screen for 5 seconds and then goes to another Action(is that right term?) which is the main page(called StartingPoint). However it crashes whilst jumping between those 2 pages. So basically, my question is why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

I created the main page first and that works fine on its own. It is just when trying to jump between those 2 pages.

**Manifest - AMENDED:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jonysapp.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.jonysapp.test.StartingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.jonysapp.test.StartingPoint" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Splash.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/mirley"
>


</LinearLayout>
```

**Splash.Java:** I have a feeling the code is wrong in here somewhere. Maybe with the Try Catch Finally?

```
package com.jonysapp.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle MirleysVariable) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(MirleysVariable);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(Splash.this, StartingPoint.class);
                Splash.this.startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

}

}
```

**StartingPoint.Java**

```
package com.jonysapp.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StartingPoint extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**LogCat:**

```
04-21 12:48:08.004: D/dalvikvm(31290): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 66K, 3% free 8887K/9091K, paused 16ms

04-21 12:48:08.014: I/dalvikvm-heap(31290): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.280MB for 1639696-byte allocation

04-21 12:48:08.044: D/dalvikvm(31290): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 10487K/10759K, paused 2ms+2ms

04-21 12:48:08.084: D/TextLayoutCache(31290): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0

04-21 12:48:08.134: D/libEGL(31290): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so

04-21 12:48:08.134: D/libEGL(31290): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so

04-21 12:48:08.144: D/libEGL(31290): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so

04-21 12:48:08.144: D/libEGL(31290): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so

04-21 12:48:08.174: D/OpenGLRenderer(31290): Enabling debug mode 0

04-21 12:48:13.094: W/dalvikvm(31290): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)

04-21 12:48:13.094: E/AndroidRuntime(31290): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2196

04-21 12:48:13.094: E/AndroidRuntime(31290): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.jonysapp.test/com.jonysapp.test.StartingPoint}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

04-21 12:48:13.094: E/AndroidRuntime(31290): at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)

04-21 12:48:13.094: E/AndroidRuntime(31290): at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)

04-21 12:48:13.094: E/AndroidRuntime(31290): at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)

04-21 12:48:13.094: E/AndroidRuntime(31290): at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)

04-21 12:48:13.094: E/AndroidRuntime(31290): at com.jonysapp.test.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:23)

04-21 12:48:13.364: D/OpenGLRenderer(31290): Flushing caches (mode 0)

04-21 12:48:13.404: D/OpenGLRenderer(31290): Flushing caches (mode 1)
```

It's very likely I have posted too much code for this question so I apologise if I have bombarded this page with too much. Although if I have missed off anything important to help, please let me know!

As a side note, if you have any tips to stop me getting into any bad habits with the coding so far, that would be appreciated (but not necessary)

Thanks again for any help!

Comment: It's god's way of telling you that splash screens are evil ;) http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Comment: haha! Well I am certainly with God on this one! Out of interest, what alternative (and better) way would there be of doing this kind of thing instead of a splash screen?

Comment: What kind of thing?  Deliberately delaying time between start and the user getting the UI?  Using up restricted resources?  I can think of many ways of doing it, but very few whys ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this messge:

> 04-21 12:48:13.094: E/AndroidRuntime(31290):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.jonysapp.test/com.jonysapp.test.StartingPoint};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

This means that you have some activity that you haven't declared in manifest file. you have used all capitals in here:

```
com.jonysapp.test.STARTINGPOINT
```

Try making it:

```
com.jonysapp.test.StartingPoint.
```

The class name is case sensitive I guess. @Trinimon is right.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Shobhit! I tried tagging you in a comment to Trinimon but in case that didn't work I thought I would thank you here anyway. However after changing the manifest like you had both said (from uppercase to lowercaser) I am still getting an error. I amended my original post with the new manifest, could you check the amended version and tell me if I did that correctly?

Comment: Try having all the activities in one application tag: eg: <application> <activity> </activity> < activity> </activity> </application> . RIght now you have 2 application tags in your manifest. Keep one and have both activities inside one. Also you have both the classes in same src folder of same package, right?

Comment: That fixed it! I'm still finding it hard to believe! Thanks to you and @Trinimon for this. You've both been a big help here in solving this and I understand the logcat a bit more now as well since you pointed out the error it mentioned!

Comment: Happy to help. All the best! Before you start playing around with android, its a good idea to read the basics android documentation of official site.  It would help you and give you an idea of how things work.

Comment: @Jonathan, you're welcome. As Shobhit Puri said, it's a good idea to start with some basic material. You could have a look at the sample apps, too. They are available for download in the SDK Manager. There are some more nice sites, e.g. http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is your issue:

> 04-21 12:48:13.094: E/AndroidRuntime(31290):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.jonysapp.test/**com.jonysapp.test.StartingPoint**};
>   have you declared this activity in your **AndroidManifest.xml**?

You have to declare the activity in your manifest, i.e.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.project.StartingPoint"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**p.s.**: added `intent-filter` for app launcher activity.

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

Comment: Well first of all, thanks to you and @Shobhit_Puri (I hope that tagged ok) for such amazingly fast responses! 


Having tried to change com.jonysapp.test.STARTINGPOINT into com.jonysapp.test.StartingPoint  it still crashes after the 5 second sleep.


I feel like I am possibly aiming it towards the wrong file? Am I correct trying to open the Java file (StartingPoint.java) or should I be trying to open the xml file (in my case it is activity_starting_point.xml). I havent put the code for that file on my original post but I can add it if it will help?


Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Dear Jonathan, you need to add the activity in the file  `AndroidManifest.xml`that is located in the root of your project. Take care of upper/lowercase letters: this `com.example.project.STARTINGPOINT` won't work if your activit y is named `StartingPoint`

Comment: Dear Trinimon. I have amended the manifest as you have said. Yet it is still bringing up the same error? I have edited my original post to the new Manifest file, could you confirm that is how it is supposed to look? Thank you again for your time, I am sure you have other things you would rather be doing on your weekend!